# How to make Syncfusion gauge "NeedlePointer" value update on Property Change Event?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, syncfusion, inotifypropertychanged

I am reading data from a LoRa scanner utilizing `SerialPort` that gets among other things, the signal strength (RSSI) that ranges between -10 and -110. I want the gauge to update automatically every time a new RSSI value is read.

I have created a `serialPortConn` class where I connect to the scanner and read the data using a function named `SerialPort_DataReceived`:

```
public void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {  
        try
        {
            while (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                 string DataIn = serialPort.ReadLine();
                 Debug.WriteLine("Data received from the scanner: " + DataIn);

                // Process the received data and extract the fields
                    Network data = ProcessReceivedData(DataIn);

                 MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        // Check if the data name is not empty or null
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Name))
                        {
                            // Find the existing network with the same name, if it exists
                            Network existingNetwork = NetworkNames.FirstOrDefault(network => network.Name == data.Name);

                            if (existingNetwork != null)
                            {
                                // Add the RSSI value to the existing network's RSSIList
                        
                                // NetworkNames.Add(new Network { RSSI = data.RSSI });
                                // strength = data.RSSI;
                                Strength = data.RSSI;
                                existingNetwork.RSSI = data.RSSI;
                                existingNetwork.Name = data.Name;

                                Debug.WriteLine("strength: " + strength);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Create a new network with the name and initialize its RSSIList 
                                NetworkNames.Add(new Network { Name = data.Name, RSSI = data.RSSI });

                                // strength = data.RSSI;
                                Strength = data.RSSI;
                            }

                            // Print the network name and its RSSIList for debugging purposes
                            foreach (Network network in NetworkNames)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("NetworkName: " + network.Name + " " + network.RSSI);
                            }

                        }
                    });
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Handle the cancellation if needed
            Debug.WriteLine("Reading data from the scanner was canceled.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions
            Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to read data from the scanner: {ex.Message}");
        }
        
    }
```

I am savig the new RSSI value to a `strength` property defined at the beginning of the `SerialPortConn` as follow:

```
public class SerialPortConn : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { 
        //public ObservableCollection<Network> NetworkNames { get; set; }
        private SerialPort serialPort;
        Network networkNames = new Network();
        public ObservableCollection<Network> NetworkNames { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Network>();
        private int strength;

        public int Strength
        {
            get { return strength; }
            //get => strength;
            set
            {
                if (strength != value)
                {
                    strength = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Strength));
                    //OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

In the content page code behind, I am trying to assign the `Strength` property to the `NeedlePointer` value as follow:

```
namespace Scanner_MAUI.Pages;

public partial class HistoricalData : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //public ObservableCollection<Network> NetworkNames { get; set; }
    private SerialPortConn scannerConn;
    public HistoricalData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        needlePointer.Value = scannerConn.Strength;
        Number.Text = scannerConn.Strength.ToString();
        scannerConn.PropertyChanged += ScannerConn_PropertyChanged;

      //..More Code
    }

    private void ScannerConn_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(scannerConn.Strength))
        {
            //MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            //{
                new HistoricalData();
                needlePointer.Value = scannerConn.Strength;
                Number.Text = scannerConn.Strength.ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine("test1 " +  needlePointer.Value);
                Debug.WriteLine("test2 " + Number.Text);
            //});
        }
    }
```

But the guage value doesn't change.
Note I did a similar approach for a list that shows Network names by adding in the code behind the following line:
`NetworkListView.ItemsSource = scannerConn.NetworkNames;`
The difference is that the names are saved in an `ObservableCollection`. And this shows the new names in the listView while the scan is running.

Finally this is the xaml:

```
 <Frame Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid>
                <gauge:SfRadialGauge x:Name="radialGauge">
                <!-- more stuff -->
                 <gauge:RadialAxis.Pointers>
                     <gauge:NeedlePointer x:Name="needlePointer"  />
                  </gauge:RadialAxis.Pointers>
                  <gauge:RadialAxis.Annotations>
                  <gauge:GaugeAnnotation x:Name="annotation" DirectionUnit="Angle" DirectionValue="90" PositionFactor="0.5">
                     <gauge:GaugeAnnotation.Content>
                         <Label x:Name="Number" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
                      </gauge:GaugeAnnotation.Content>
                        </gauge:GaugeAnnotation>
                       <!-- more stuff -->
```

**Update!!!!**
this is the console out put of the data I get:

```
strength: -24
15:24:50:061    existingNetwork: device_1_dummy -24
15:24:50:061    NetworkName: device_1_dummy -24
15:24:50:061    NetworkName: device_1_dummy -24
15:24:50:061    NetworkName: device_1_dummy -25
15:24:52:309    Data received from the scanner: message: datastearm, name: b'device_1_dummy', type: LoRaRAW, lat: None, lon: None, rssi: -25, snr: 6.0, time: (2023, 6, 15, 20, 32, 39, 775777, None)

strength: -25
....and so on
```

The negative number is the RSSI value I am after.
With the dummy data that I am getting there is only one network name however the RSSI value changes all the time. I tried using on click and  on Item selected events. With These I only get one RSSI value and it shows on the gauge.
**PLEASE NOT I AM A NOOBIE STILL :)**

Comment: Are you getting more than one value from the serial port?  I like starting by testing the device with PUTTY.  You can send messages and then check response.  Often in cases like this user forgot to terminate command with a return or is using the wrong type of return.  I have solved hundreds of serial port issues.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I do get different values. I can edit the question and show the console output. Note that I don't have an issue with getting and extracting the data (I think at least).

Comment: Are you getting to the Changed Event?  The code is registering the event using "+=".  I do not see the method HistoricalData() being called.

Comment: Exactly I am not getting there I believe. Should it be called in the `ScannerConn_PropertyChanged`? Edit. HistoricalData() is not a method. I'll update the question again.

Comment: in `SerialPort_DataReceived` you are setting `strenght` which is a **private field**, not `Strength` which is a **public property**.  The latter fires a `ProppertyChanged` event, the former does not

Comment: It is a constructor which is still a method.  You need in the code "new HistoricalData()" to execute the constructor.  This will register the event.

Comment: I updated my code also I will update the question. Still not working. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: @jdweng it is a page constructor, it will be called when the page is created

Comment: @Jason you are a wizard mate. I changed it to Strength. Now It works. Thanks a lot!!! if   you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Put a break point an see if you are getting to the constructor.  If you are not getting to the method than check to see if page is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `SerialPort_DataReceived` you are setting `strength` which is a **private field**, not `Strength` which is a **public property**. The latter fires a `PropertyChanged` event, the former does not